# Upload from shell to HTTP Server

Tags: shell, scp, http

I use `scp` command to upload file from my local computer to my ftp server 
is there any tools to do the same thing with http server (like Apache server ) like `scp` do ?

Comment: You could leverage `curl` or `wget`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to run some program under an Apache server that handles requests to where to put the files and authentication based on the url and data supplied. There are of course CMS systems that offer you all that, but none with the ease of use uploading multiple files like you can do with `scp`.

The shell based programs would all upload one at a time AFAIK, you could of course write something that posts multiple files in one go.
The other disadvantages of such an approach is that it is vastly more difficult to do private/public key authentication using an HTTP server compared to copying your public key to an ssh server using `ssh-copy-id`